# How to define a function that decrease a number half of itself repeatedly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am studying statistics on MIT open courses. I will attach the image of the question.
In an example:
I want to get the below value:

```
[1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625 ...]
```

I have tried a recursive way to solve this problem.
Which  is like

```py
import numpy as np

def halfe(x):
   return x/2

A = np.array([[.8, .3],
              [.2, .7]])
#if I put dot usage of np i get the correct solution for the first iteration
u0 = np.array([1,0])
u1 = A.dot(u0)
print(u1)
[0.8 0.2]
#now the new value will be used to iterate for another value. In an example:
u2 = A.dot(u1)

######### also I made a broken solution for  this ############

def halfer(x):
    return x/2

for i in range(0,10):
    B = A.dot(halfer(np.array([[1],[0]])))

#but I am completely on a different page...
```

I will attach the image of the question. My target is to make a recursive function to iterate it easily.

I would be glad If you could reply [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzYrH.png)

Comment: Welcome @Filiumbelli. The good news is that you came to the right place.  The bad news is that this is NOT a place to come to if you want your term paper written FOR you.  You ARE welcome to restate your question as fully as you can within this page, and please be sure to include the steps YOU have taken to achieve YOUR objective.  Folks here will be glad to ASSIST you along the way once they see that YOU have made a good faith effort which means you should submit a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well here is the thing. I have a question that I can not explain verbally. So my target is to visualize it to get a better explanation or a recursive solution. Maybe there is a specific name or a module for this problem. That's why I directly written the solution of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need any recursive function. A for loop can accomplish it:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[.8, .3], [.2, .7]])
u0 = np.array([1,0])

# Initialize list U to store values of u_i

U=[u0]
N=3
for i in range(N):
   U.append(A@U[-1])
   print(f'u{i+1} value is {U[-1]}')

u1 value is [0.8 0.2]
u2 value is [0.7 0.3]
u3 value is [0.65 0.35]

U
[array([1, 0]), 
 array([0.8, 0.2]),
 array([0.7, 0.3]),
 array([0.65, 0.35])]
```

I don't really understand why you need an `halfer` function. But if you still do, you can either use a list comprehension to do that:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
[a/2.0**i for i in range(5)]

[array([1., 2., 3.]),
 array([0.5, 1. , 1.5]),
 array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75]),
 array([0.125, 0.25 , 0.375]),
 array([0.0625, 0.125 , 0.1875])]
```

Comment: Oh i got it. Thank you. I could not make it easy for myself. Thanks for the answer again..